# SharePoint XML Parse c#

Tags: c#, xml

I have such XML structure which was returned by SharePoint web services.

```
<rs:data ItemCount="4" xmlns:rs="urn:company:rowset">
  <z:row ows_AssetId="HP010336520"  />
  <z:row ows_AssetId="HP010336519"  />
  <z:row ows_AssetId="HP010354403"  />
  <z:row ows_AssetId="HP010357062"  />
</rs:data>

    private static void Parser(List<XmlNode> data)
    {

        List<XmlNodeList> rows = (from row in data.AsEnumerable()
                            select row.SelectNodes("data/row")).ToList();
    }
```

I was trying to query for a row, but no luck. Could you guys please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use an XmlNamespaceManager when querying the node list. Not seen in your code is the declaration of the 'z' namespace in the document's root: xmlns:z="#RowsetSchema".

Try the following in your Parser method:

```
    NameTable nameTable = new NameTable();
    XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(nameTable);
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("z", "#RowsetSchema");

    List<XmlNodeList> rows = (from row in data.AsEnumerable()
                              select row.SelectNodes("//z:row", nsmgr)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks!! looks like something happens, but all XmlNodes are with empty body... : - (

Comment: Right, that's consistent with your fragment.
<z:row ows_AssetId="HP010357062"  />

There's an **attribute** in your node, ows_AssetId, but there is no **text** content in the node. If there was text content, your fragment might look like:
<z:row ows_AssetId="HP010357062">Hello World</z:row>.

You can query this by using the '@' sign: 

`List<XmlNodeList> rows = (from row in data.AsEnumerable()
                              select row.SelectNodes("//z:row[@ows_AssetId='HP010357062']", nsmgr)).ToList();`

and you can get the value in a similar way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not at a place where I can test right now, but I believe at least part of the issue is your omission of namespaces in your query -- rather than "data/row", try "rs:data/z:row".

Comment: Thanks! Could you please explain me what is rs and z is?

Comment: Namespaces are a way to resolve potential naming clashes in identifiers. They also indicate that an element exists within a certain context.

Namespaces are indicated by text before the element names, so the namespaces in your fragment are 'rs' and 'z'. For much more detailed information, take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302166.aspx.